# Distinguishing structs with type traits

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

Is there a way to distinguish a `struct` which has a `std::vector<T>` from any other type?

I have some template functions which should be specialized if `T` is a struct that contains a `std::vector<T>` so what I'm looking for is:

```
template<typename T> method(const T& object)
{
  static_assert(!contains_vector<T>::value, "This method must be specialized");
  // implementation
}
```

so that

```
struct Foo {
  uint32_t foo;
  float bar;
};

struct Bar {
  uint16_t foo;
  vector<float> bar;
}

contains_vector<float>::value == false;
contains_vector<Foo>::value == false;
contains_vector<Bar>::value == true;
```

I was trying to figure out how could I distinguish through `<type_traits>` this difference.

Comment: Why do you want to investigate an implementation detail of some class?

Comment: Sounds like an XY-problem. Can you explain why you need to treat things containing a `vector` differently?

Comment: What keeps you from inheriting `bar` from `xyz` and use `is_base_of<xyz,bar>`, or any other detour ?

Comment: I have a lot of plain structs which I need to serialize, all of them contain just fundamental types (numbers or enum constants) or other plain structs or a vector of structs/fundamental types. I need to write a template specialization to manage the structs that contain vectors (as I have to serialize the contained elements and I must make sure that it is impossible to try to serialize a struct with a vector which doesn't have its template specialization.

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection, so what you're asking for is not possible in the general case.

Comment: @Barry: in the general case I know, but I though about anything from <type_traits> which holds for fundamental types and structs made of just fundamental types.

Comment: even if you knew it contained a vector, how would you plan to serialize differently? You'd need to walk through the elements and determine which ones are vectors.

Comment: What about detecting the simple types using is_pod or is_standard_layout?

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, no. C++ doesn't have reflection. So if you want to write a type trait "does this arbitrary generic struct contain a member that is a `vector`?", that's impossible.

However, if you control all the types that you want to test, you could instrument them with [`BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html), which sort of adds reflection:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Foo,
    (uint32_t, foo)
    (float, bar)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Bar,
    (uint16_t, foo)
    (std::vector<float>, bar)
)
```

That makes your structs `Foo` and `Bar` function as if they were `boost::fusion` sequences from the get-go. After that, writing a type trait just involves all the usual Boost Fusion metaprogramming hackery:

```
template <typename Seq>
struct contains_vector {
    // metafunction class for checking if a type is a std::vector<T,A>
    struct is_vector {
        template <typename T>
        struct apply : std::false_type { };

        template <typename T, typename A>
        struct apply<std::vector<T,A>> : std::true_type { };    
    };

    // think std::find_if()
    using iter = typename boost::fusion::result_of::find_if<Seq, is_vector>::type;
    // think .end()
    using end = typename boost::fusion::result_of::end<Seq>::type;

    // if iter == end, it's not found, so have to flip the sign
    using type = std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_same<iter, end>::value>;
};
```

With that:

```
static_assert(contains_vector<Bar>::type::value, "");    // OK
static_assert(!contains_vector<Foo>::type::value, "");   // OK
```

Note that I'm using [`find_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/query/metafunctions/find_if.html) and [`end`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/sequence/intrinsic/metafunctions/end.html) instead of using [`any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/query/metafunctions/any.html), because that one as a metafunction always returns `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) (Substitution failure is not an error)

```
struct Foo {
  uint32_t foo;
  float bar;
};

struct Bar {
  typedef vector<float> bar_vector;
  uint16_t foo;
  bar_vector bar;
};
```

Notice the addition of the typedef in struct Bar.

```
template <typename T>
struct contains_vector {
    // Types "yes" and "no" are guaranteed to have different sizes,
    // specifically sizeof(yes) == 1 and sizeof(no) == 2.
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename C>
    static yes& test(typename C::bar_vector*);

    template <typename>
    static no& test(...);

    // If the "sizeof" of the result of calling test<T>(nullptr) is equal to sizeof(yes),
    // the first overload worked and T has a nested type named foobar.
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

You can then determine if the struct contains the typedef indicating a vector is present:

```
std::cout << contains_vector<int>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << contains_vector<Bar>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << contains_vector<Foo>::value << std::endl;
```

It can be simplified in C++11.